# Why does my BroadcastReceiver continually receive the same broadcast?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

My `Application` class creates an alarm and receives the system broadcast once per day.  In the `onReceive()` it sends an application broadcast that is received by my MainActivity class.

The problem is that the `onReceive()` in the MainActivity class is continually called whenever an orientation change occurs.  I understand why `onResume()` is called across orientation changes, but I don't understand why `onReceive()` is also getting called.

I assumed that because the `Application` class only sends out the local broadcast once, my 
MainActivity would only receive the broadcast once.

Does anyone know why `onReceive()` in my MainActivity class is continually called?

Here is the `onCreate()` in my `Application` class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    // register a receiver in the Application class to receive a broadcast
    // at the start of each day
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(START_OF_DAY_ACTION);
    startOfDayReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(TaskReminderApp.this, 
                           "Application: startofday broadcast received", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        

            // send a broadcast to MainActivity
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(TEST_ACTION); 

            context.sendBroadcast(i);     
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(startOfDayReceiver, intentFilter);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);  // for testing purposes
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);       // for testing purposes
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);        
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(START_OF_DAY_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);    
}
```

Here is `onResume()` and `onPause()` in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(TEST_ACTION);
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            // This is getting called on every orientation change
            // and every time the activity resumes.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                          "MainActivity: broadcast received", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);    
} 

@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();

    // I thought this might be the problem, but it makes no
    // difference if I comment it out.
    this.unregisterReceiver(receiver); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by sending a local application broadcast instead of a system broadcast.

In my class that extends `Application`, I send a local broadcast like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(TEST_ACTION);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
```

Then in my MainActivity class, I define a `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                       "MainActivity: broadcast received", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

I register the receiver in MainActivity's `onCreate()`:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver,
        new IntentFilter(TEST_ACTION));
```

Then I unregister the receiver in MainActivity's `onDestroy()`:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

It works well now and I only receive a single broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to create the Receiver in your onCreate(). Else it will be created again and again and again..

The registering is just fine, same as the unregistering.

Comment: I tried that but it's still receiving the broadcast on each orientation change.  I even set a flag to check if it's already been created (and saved the state of the flag using onSaveInstanceState), but it's not working.